# Very large HTTP request vs many small requests

Tags: json, client-server

I need a 2D array (as Json) to be sent from server to client. It would be around 400x400 in size with each entry around 4 characters of text. So that makes it around 640KB of data.

Which of the following extreme approaches is better ?

1. I make a large HTTP request of all the data at one go.
2. I make 400 requests - each asking for a single row (around 1.6 KB)

I believe optimal approach would be somewhere in middle. Could anyone give me an idea what might be the optimal single request size for this data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Unless you are dealing with slow (**very** slow by today's standards) connections and really **need** incremental updates, do it in one request.

That gives you better efficiency for [compressing the response](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip), and avoids the overhead of the [extra HTTP requests and response headers](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#num_http).

Comment: +1 - and you avoid the overhead of the round trips. Even at 20ms.... 400 requests would make that 8000ms overhead = 8 seconds. At 80ms... (far away), this would be 32 seconds wasted.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both David & Tom. That was really useful. :)

Comment: Well, @TomTom you didn't factor in parallel requests...! its only 20ms in the beginning and at the end on a perfect connection if there's no limit on concurrent connections :) Correct me if I'm wrong, it's only 400 x (amount of time taken to process headers) and not 400 x RTT

Comment: @ZekeDran — Browsers impose a limit on the number of concurrent connections.

Comment: Assuming it's six, the final value is reduced by 6 times, that's close to 1.33 seconds; Hence if there's no progressive processing, this 1.33s would still be a waste!

Answer (score 91):

Couple of considerations for choosing one big vs several small:

- In the single request case, you can't do progressive data processing as the data arrives; you need to wait for the full packet to arrive before you can do anything. If it fails, you need to start everything from scratch.
- In the multiple requests case, you can do progressive data processing. However, you now have to consider the potential for multiple failures and how to recover from these.
- Multiple requests incur overhead for each request. This is additional bandwidth you app will be consuming.
- Some HTTP agents limit the number of concurrent requests to the same server, and you might need to do some logic to work around that.
- Response compression will work better for the single request case.
- Multiple requests won't require you to allocate the full memory for your data. Granted, 640KB is not that big chunk of memory, so that might not be a big consideration for you, depending on how often you will allocate it.
- In the case of early terminate of the process (either a Cancel button or the app is terminated or the browser navigates away from your page), the single request will still finish the full response download; however, for the multiple requests case, any request your code hasn't started yet will not be executed.

Honestly, I wouldn't be that worried about the last two and would base my choice on 1) is progressive data processing important; and 2) what your app tolerance is for failures and partial data.

Comment: +1 I find this a much better answer than the currently accepted one for such a case since it provides a good comparison of the two options rather than a direct answer.

Comment: Consider caching/busting too. A single request that is cached means any change leads to another large request. Split into multiple requests, any change only needs to download that chunk again.

Answer (score 3):

And you have to keep in mind that the servers may have [vulnerabilities with large requests](http://tomcat.apache.org/security-6.html#Fixed_in_Apache_Tomcat_6.0.36).