# several petitions vs single petition node.js

Tags: node.js, express

So far in my Angular2 app I have a get petition to express.js server into a loop which is run n times and retrieve n data. So I'm making n get petitions to the server.

I'm wondering what should be faster, keep it like that, or just ask 1 get petition and retrieve those n data directly from the server

Comment: um... run an experiment?  Lots of things to consider - concurrency in the browser, on the server.  wire time. data access time.  The other bit to consider is not the overall performance of the data load but the way the user will experience it - they may be willing to wait longer for all the data,  IF the data they most likely want is available quickly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Very large HTTP request vs many small requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138371/very-large-http-request-vs-many-small-requests)