# App engine urlfetch: how to get the full response with allow_truncate = true ?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, urlfetch

I've faced `ResponseTooLargeError` when using AppEngine's `urlfetch.fetch` because my response was several Mb big. ([doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.urlfetch))

I see there is a `allow_truncate` param I can pass and it will truncate the response if too big. Is there any way then to request the rest of the response ? Something like making new calls to the same URL with an offset ?

Otherwise I don't really understand how this param can be useful (just checking if it returns without error ?)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way of requesting the "rest of the response", it all depends on the particular server-side implementation of the service you're working with: if it offers support for transferring data in smaller chunks, and, if it does, how exactly that works, i.e. the exact protocol for performing such transfers. Some may even consider such capability a part of the service itself.

Just to get an idea of what the implementation *might* look like you can see some possible options for a particular service discussed in [Very large HTTP request vs many small requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138371/very-large-http-request-vs-many-small-requests)

Yes, the usefulness of the option is to be able to get a partial response vs just getting a `ResponseTooLargeError` (which *might* be sufficient in some cases).